# What does it mean to perform calculus upon functions of complex values?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Complex numbers exist in a plane. This would lead me to believe that calculus views them as multivariate, but I am not real sure. How would one define a rate of change for a complex number valued function, or the area underneath it. Could someone explain this in simple terms?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too broad: This is the subject of essentially every introductory textbook on complex analysis, and cannot be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @T.Bongers I only asked what it means to integrate and differentiate. That cannot possibly be too broad.

Comment: @T.Bongers the question *was* answered. It is clearly not too broad.

Answer (score 1):

At a very simple level, any complex number $z$ can be expressed as $x + i y.$
and $f(z) = u(x,y) + i v (x,y)$

The definition of derivative is the same definition.

$f'(z) = \lim_\limits{z\to z_0} \frac {f(z) - f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$

$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac {\partial u}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\
\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} = - \frac {\partial v}{\partial y} + i\frac {\partial v}{\partial x} $

if $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac {\partial f}{\partial y}$ then the function is said to be "holomorphic."

Comment: Why did you put a multivariate function next to u and i?

Comment: z has a real component and an imaginary component.  At the introductory level, at least, it is best to think of them as independent.

Comment: ah I see. That makes sense.

Comment: Your answer is probably superior mathemtically but the other feels more descriptive and easier to understand, and so I choose to accept it over yours. Great answer though! You certainly didnt make it easy for me to decide! :D

Answer (score 1):

When you compute the rate of change of a real valued function via a derivative, you are finding a very local linear approximation ( a line in 1 d, plane for scalar maps of two variables , and hyperplanes as you go up).

In complex analysis, it works a bit differently, at least visually. You can view infinitesimal changes of the complex component and real component. While this can be thought of as the partial derivatives of a multi variable function from the 2d reals with this $i$ symbol and this measures the rate of change in one of the two directions on the complex plane with respect to the real or imaginary input, thanks to Euler's formula, this manifests itself visually as a local infinitesimal rotation and translation, rather than say a tangent plane.

Comment: What about integration, or is that nonsense? Also, what do you mean by a rotation and translation? Are you referring to the angular changes caused by the square root of i?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck yes that's where the rotation comes from. Yes! You can integrate and that's where a lot of the magic happens. There are lots of integrals that are really tough to integrate in the reals and easy to integrate using complex analysis with a technique called contour integration.

Comment: Interesting. I will have to look it up!